# CURRENT_DATE getting the month and year

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently using the CURRENT_DATE when inserting into my table field for the Date. Pull just the Month and Year two digit month and four digit year (ex $mon = 01 and $year 2010)

Comment: could you be a little bit more descriptive, or maybe give an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see [date-and-time-functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

```
"SELECT MONTH(datefiled) as month, YEAR(datefield) as yeah FROM table"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$date = date("m  Y");
list($mon, $year) = explode(" ", $date);
```

Basically, the [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function takes a format string (`m` is the two-digit numerical month, `Y` is a four-digit year) and produces a string representation of the date.  Then you can use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to store the split-up values you need in the variables `$mon` and `$year`.

Edit: of course, the `$date` variable is not needed.

```
list($mon, $year) = explode(" ", date("m Y"));
```

This will work just as well.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are looking for but if you trying to get the current date in year-month-day notation, the below code should help.

```
$DATE = date('Y-m-d');
```

If you are trying to pull the information from the table,

```
$date_from_table = $row['DateField'];
$DATE = date('Y m', strtotime($date_from_table));
```